# Mhchem broken on mobile

Tags: bug, status-completed, mathjax, mhchem

[image]

That's how it looks right now. I don't recall this being a problem earlier. It's like this on other questions as well.

Link to the answer in question: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/55285/16683

Was it broken by some update? I haven't been around much so haven't been following what's been going on.

Thanks.

Comment: The mhchem extension of MathJax on Chemistry.SE has been updated (apparently yesterday to version 3.0.1 and just now to version 3.0.2), which also causes a changed appearance of several posts.

Comment: Yes, the mhchem extension has been updated. But the red `\ce` indicates that it wasn't loaded at all.

Comment: Could you add the `mathjax` tag to the question?

Comment: Confirmed with Android app, installed today.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This bug was caused by [/sites route in the stackexchange api](http://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/sites?page=2&pagesize=100) not returning `MHChemMathJax` in `markdown_extensions` due to configuration changes for the mhchem 3.0 upgrade. The fix is already rolled out, so the apps should be rendering mhchem after a restart.

However, the apps are using embedded mathjax & mhchem .js files. We'll need to update the apps in order to get the latest 3.0 mhchem version in.

Comment: Thanks. Could you take a look at http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/how-to-write-physical-units/3287#comment4729_3287 I can confirm that the Android App (Version 1.0.89) cannot render `\pu` ($\pu{123 kJ//mol}$).